# como genero un bucle para el diccionario?

Tags: c#

okey primero quiero explicar de que trata el programa que trato de hacer y otros detalles
1.el programa es un ejercicio que mi profesor me puso de tarea en el que tenia que crear un diccionario en el que un nombre serviría como clave y un numero telefónico sea el valor
y como condición los elementos tienen que ser implementados en tiempo de ejecución ósea no pueden ir en el código como tal
2. el código esta incompleto debido a que me quede bien frustrado porque no sabia que hacer y no se me ocurría nada
3 intente usar un goto ya que pensé que si ponía un goto que se devolviera el if principal después solo tendría que poner un else con un break y listo pero no se como hacerlo XD.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> directorio = new Dictionary<string, int>();
       
        Console.WriteLine("le gustaria crear una lista de contactos, si quieres decir si usa un 1 y si quieres decir no usa 0: ");

        int b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (b == 1)
        {
            

            Console.WriteLine("inserte un nombre :");
            string f = (Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("inserte un numero de telefono :");
            int g = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            directorio.Add(f, g);

        }
        Console.WriteLine("quiere insertar otro contacto,si quieres decir si usa un 1 y si quieres decir no usa 0: ");
        int h = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (h == 1)
        {
           
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Podrías utilizar un [do...while()](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements#the-do-statement), para encapsular la lógica de tu programa y lograr que se ejecute al menos una vez, y luego se siga ejecutando mientras la condición se cumpla

Comment: Tu problema basicamente es como hacer que tu codigo se repita X cantidad de veces (o para siempre)?

Comment: deberias tener una opcion que sea "Printar lista de contactos" y cuando el usuario elija eso iteras el diccionario para printarlos a la consola. https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-5.0

Comment: gbianchi pues el chiste del codigo era que el usiario pidiera cuando parar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues una opción sería con un menú previo

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> directorio = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        int opcion;


        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Elija una opción :");
            Console.WriteLine("1 - Ingresar un contacto :");
            Console.WriteLine("2 - Leer definición :");
            Console.WriteLine("3 - Salir :");
            Console.WriteLine("Opción elegida :");

            opcion = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (opcion)
            {

                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("inserte un nombre :");
                    string f = (Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("inserte un numero de telefono :");
                    int g = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    directorio.Add(f, g);
                    break;
                case 2:

                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("Gracias por utilizar nuestra Agenda :");
                    break;
            }

        } while (opcion != 3);
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
```

Comment: oye gracias por tu ayuda pero encontre un fallo y es que si inserto un numero de 10 cifras para arriba me da una excepcion de overflow y dice que el int 32 no puede almacenar un valor tan grande mirare como lo soluciono de verdad me sirvio mucho tu ayuda

Comment: Si te sirvió, acepta la respuesta para cerrar la pregunta. Gracias

Comment: Por cierto, generalmente, las variables int, sean de 16, 32 o 64 bit, se usan para realizar cálculos con ellas. En el caso de un número de teléfono, no lo usarás para ningún cálculo, por lo que te recomiendo lo metas como un String, además de esa manera podrías formatear la entrada para que te separe los dígitos tipo 333 333 333. Un saludo